# Are two stochastic processes independent if the Wiener processes inside are uncorrelated

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, correlation, covariance, wienerprocess

Assume there are two stochastic processes:
$dx_t = \alpha_1(x_t,t)dt + \beta_1(x_t,t)dW^1_t$
and $dy_t = \alpha_2(y_t,t)dt + \beta_2(y_t,t)dW^2_t$.

Does $dW^1_t\times{dW^2_t} = 0$ imply that $\operatorname{cov}(x_t, y_t) = 0$?

If it does, please give me a proof.

Answer (score 3):

**[Edit]**

My "answer" below is not a really an answer for I have completely misinterpreted your original question. I thought you asked about the covariance of 2 processes over a given time horizon (i.e. for a fixed $\omega$) and not the covariance of two random variables (fixed $t$). Also note that $\text{cov}(x,y)=0$ does not mean that $x$ and $y$ are independent (except special case where they have an elliptic distribution), it just means they are uncorrelated (Pearson linear correlation assumed).

---

No this is not true in general.

Take the example below where I've assumed
\begin{gather}
dX_t = X_t( r_X dt + \sigma_X dW_t^X ),\ \ X(0) = X_0 \\
dY_t = X_t( r_Y dt + \sigma_Y dW_t^Y ),\ \ Y(0) = Y_0 \\
d\langle W^X, W^Y \rangle_t = \rho_{XY}
\end{gather}
with
\begin{gather}
 X_0 = 1, Y_0 = 2 \\
 r_X = 50\%, r_Y = -50\%\\
 \sigma_X = 50\%, \sigma_Y = 25\%
\end{gather}

Now take $\rho_{XY} = 0\%$ and you get the figure below: although the Brownian increments are uncorrelated (here represented through the log-returns, bottom subplot), the processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$ clearly exhibit significant correlation (see top subplot with a significant sample Pearson correlation).

This is essentially due to the **drift terms** in the SDE.

[image]

---

Note that if you take $\rho_{XY}=99\%$ you won't see that correlation (recall it is a correlation between local increments) transpire at the global level either, see below

[image]

Comment: It appears to me that $cov(X_t, Y_t)=0$, if $\rho_{X,Y}=0$.

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to me: neither when starting from BehrouzMaleki's hint nor from my simulations. Could you explain your reasoning?

Comment: What I meant was from a formulaic perspective based on your dynamics, since they are log-normal, the co-variance can be computed explicitly.

Comment: I realise that my answer has nothing to do with the initial question. I was talking about the cross-sectional covariance  (fixed realisation) while you talk about the covariance between two random variables. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

By Integration, we have
$$x_t=x_{0}+\int_{0}^{t} \alpha_1(x_s,s)ds+\int_{0}^{t} \beta_1(x_s,s)dW_1(s)$$
$$y_t=y_{0}+\int_{0}^{t} \alpha_2(y_s,s)ds+\int_{0}^{t} \beta_2(y_s,s)dW_2(s)$$
then
$$E[x_t]=x_0+E\left[\int_{0}^{t} \alpha_1(x_s,s)ds\right]$$
$$E[y_t]=y_0+E\left[\int_{0}^{t} \alpha_2(y_s,s)ds\right]$$
Now we apply Ito's lemma 
$$d(x_ty_t)=x_tdy_t+y_tdx_t+\underbrace{d[x_t,y_t]}_{0}$$
as a result
$$x_ty_t=x_0y_0+\int_{0}^{t}x_sdy_s+\int_{0}^{t}y_sdx_s$$
on the other hand
$$Cov(x_t,y_t)=E[x_ty_t]-E[x_t]E[y_t]$$

Comment: I also got that hint by myself but I got stuck at that stage. So, please give me more detail for example whether $\operatorname{cov}$ is zero or not.